# Docker commiting changes overrides default start command

Tags: docker, package, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/.
Typically I run the notebook using this command

`docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /home/folder/Projects/:/home/jovyan/Projects  -e NB_UID=1000  jupyter/datascience-notebook`

This works perfectly and I am presented with the message that notebook is running. I am able to create notebooks, run them etc.
Now I want to install the jupyter contrib extenstions from https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions. I followed the instructions here at: https://gist.github.com/glamp/74188691c91d52770807.
Using
`docker run -it jupyter/datascience-notebook /bin/bash`
command I am able to enter the container. Then I use pip and bash to install the package. All this goes smoothly.I exit the container and commit the changes using the container id.

`docker commit containerid imagename`

The problem is after committing the changes, when I run the container I am presented with bash prompt instead of the notebook start command.

Is there a way to commit package installation changes without changing the starting command of the image. Alternatively is there a way to edit the container image without actually running the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have committed a container that was started with the command `/bin/bash`.

What you need to is start the container normally using The command that you provided initially adding the `-d` option to free the terminal:

```
docker run -it --rm -d --name datascience-notebook -p 8888:8888 -v /home/folder/Projects/:/home/jovyan/Projects  -e NB_UID=1000  jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

Then from the terminal exec into the container and install the `contrib extenstions`.

```
docker exec -it datascience-notebook /bin/bash
```

Exit the container and commit the image:

```
docker commit datascience-notebook <imagename>
```

**Update:**

In case the extension can't be installed when the container is running, the solution is to build a custom Docker image from using a Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
RUN <installation commands>
```

Finally build the image using `docker build -t <image-name> .` and run the image built.

Comment: I tried that too, The problem with that is there is a command which cannot be run when the jupyter server is running: *jupyter contrib nbextension install --user*

Comment: @Sarvo Updated answer, the recommended Docker way for customizing images is to extend the image by creating a Dockerfile and building an image from that dockerfile.